# How to create and render an app.json file for Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, package.json

I am a node.js developer and I'm having trouble with building my app.json file. I want to build an app.json file so I can explicitly assign buildpacks to Heroku for deployment.

I manually created an app.json but I can tell it doesn't render like my package.json file. For example when I do `npm init` I get a package.json file with a color scheme and logo. When I create a app.json file I receive no color with the same logo you get when you create a .txt file.

app.json

```
"buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer"
    },
    {
      "url": "heroku/nodejs"
    }
  ]
  ,
  {
  "repository": "https://github.com/KeshawnSharper/BackEnd/tree/master""
}
```

Comment: You can mark the question as solved if it is

Answer (score 2):

A json file start with { and finish with } is that the case in your file ?